# Emojis showing up as question marks in app made using swift(iOS), java(android), ruby(server), mongodb(database)

Tags: ios, ruby, swift, mongodb, emoji

I've been working on this chatting application in which users can send emojis. Now I'm taking the string from whatever user enters in the UITextField and put it in NSDictionary and sending it to the server as json. And that json is sent to the server where the message is read as string in ruby and then stored in mongodb. Now when the other client make the get messages api call, the emojis are showing up as a box or a '?'. 
P.S : only emojis with 5 character code shows up like that for eg: \u1F602
but the emojis with 4 character code shows up fine for eg: \u2764

Now I don't know if the problem is client or server or the database so I don't know which code to add here. Please add in comments the code you need I'll post it here.

It feels like the problem is server, cause the problem is caused in both android and iOS devices.

Have been banging my head on this for more than a month now. Would love if someone can help.

Thanks

----EDIT----

I understand that in ruby \u{1F602} works but I don't know how to make the clients send it in that format. I'm just taking whatever user types in the UITextField(for iOS) and EditText(for Android) and sending them as it is. 
Is there a way I can make that change in client or fix it on server somehow?

Comment: Why do you expect `\u1F602` to ever work in ruby?

Comment: I don't know which format, the clients are sending the emoji in. So can't make that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer. This is how I fixed it

For Android:
in your gradle file add the following dependency

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

and then while sending a message to server encode the text using this

```
String msg = "User message here with emoji";
msg = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(msg);
```

and to decode the message after receiving from the server, use the following command

```
String msg = "User message here with emoji";
msg = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(text);
```

For iOS:
(Using @Ankit Chauhan's answer)

```
let msg:String = ""

extension String {
var encodeEmoji: String{
    if let encodeStr = NSString(cString: self.cString(using: .nonLossyASCII)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
        return encodeStr as String
    }
    return self
 }
}
let msgdata:String = msg.encodeEmoji
```

And to decode use this:

```
extension String {
var decodeEmoji: String{
    let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let decodedStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)
    if let str = decodedStr{
        return str as String
    }
    return self
 }
}

let decodedstring = "Your Unicode String".decodeEmoji
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS,

**For encode emojis to unicode use below code:**

```
let msg:String = ""

extension String {
    var encodeEmoji: String{
        if let encodeStr = NSString(cString: self.cString(using: .nonLossyASCII)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
            return encodeStr as String
        }
        return self
    }
}

let msgdata:String = msg.encodeEmoji

send encoded string to server..
```

**For decode unicode to emojis use below code:**

```
While getting your responce from the server which is unicode. 
decode that unicode to Emoji with below code

extension String {
    var decodeEmoji: String{
        let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
        let decodedStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII.rawValue)
        if let str = decodedStr{
            return str as String
        }
        return self
    }
}

let decodedstring = "Your Unicode String".decodeEmoji
```

Comment: I would've marked this as the correct answer. But I asked for both iOS and android and this was iOS only.
But thank you so much for this. Helped.
I've added this in my answer and tagged you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplified notation without curly brackets assumes there are four digits following `\u`. For 3-bytes one should use the complete expression:

```
▶ "\u{1F602}"
#⇒ ""
```

Comment: I know making it \u{1F602} works in ruby but I don't know how to make the client send it in that format.
I edited the question

Comment: Then you are to parse the raw data and construct the unicode character yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For **Android** I had to do 2 things.

1. Use escapeJava when i send msg to server and unescapeJava when receive msg

   ```
   'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3' //deprecated, dont use
    org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.2'

    StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message)
    StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(message)
   ```
2. Use EmojiCompat library from google

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html